# on ontap event want to show small rectangle with some data

Tags: android

I have created map application and on map i m showing the users,I want to show small rectangle on clicking the users on the map with some details of that user. Please give me some idea to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/balloon-itemized-overlay/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/discalis/android/maps) is the great tutorial for your requirement .

To achieve your requirement you need to use itemized-overlay it will show a info when you click on map's item.